# Error with combineLatest and strict typings - "No overload matches this call."

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire2

Recently updated a project from Angular v9 to v11.  Opted for strict typing and got a bazillion errors of course, stumped on this one.

Using combineLatest to generate a publication from 3 observables (each is a firebase doc.valueChanges() or collection.valueChanges())

My code:

```
getEdition(editionId: string): AngularFirestoreDocument<Edition> {
    return this.afs.collection('editions').doc(editionId);
}

const editionRef: Observable<Edition | undefined> = this.editionService.getEdition(ed.id).valueChanges();

combineLatest([editionRef, sectionsRef, articlesRef]).subscribe(([edition, sections, articles]: [Edition, Section[], Article[]]) => {
   // do stuff, returns void
});
```

Edition.ts:

```
import { Moment } from 'moment';

export interface Edition {
  id: string;
  pubTypeId: string;
  date: string | Moment;
  imgCaption: string;
  imgCredit: string;
  imgLink: string;
  imgSrc: string;
  introText: string;
  hasPreface: boolean;
  preface: string;
  printLink: string;
}
```

My error:

```
error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 5, '(observer?: NextObserver<[Edition | undefined, DocumentData, DocumentData]> | ErrorObserver<[Edition | undefined, DocumentData, DocumentData]> | CompletionObserver<...> | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '([edition, sections, articles]: [Edition, Section[], Article[]]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NextObserver<[Edition | undefined, DocumentData, DocumentData]> | ErrorObserver<[Edition | undefined, DocumentData, D
ocumentData]> | CompletionObserver<...> | undefined'.
      Property 'complete' is missing in type '([edition, sections, articles]: [Edition, Section[], Article[]]) => void' but required in type 'CompletionObserver<[Edition | undefined, DocumentData, DocumentData]>'.
  Overload 2 of 5, '(next?: ((value: [Edition | undefined, DocumentData, DocumentData]) => void) | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '([edition, sections, articles]: [Edition, Section[], Article[]]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: [Edition | undefined, DocumentData, DocumentData]) => void'.
      Types of parameters '__0' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type '[Edition | undefined, DocumentData, DocumentData]' is not assignable to type '[Edition, Section[], Article[]]'.
          Type 'Edition | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Edition'.
            Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Edition'.
```

I know I need to tweak my typings somehow, but not sure quite what to do given that I'm using combineLatest here...

Comment: My guess is that somewhere along the chain of `editionRef -> edition -> Edition` you have an implicit `any` type. from the docs: _Any variable, parameter or property that is initialized with null or undefined will have type any, even if strict null checks is turned on._ - So I would start by trying to find an uninitialized, `undefined` or `null` variable within that chain.

Comment: If so, I'm not able to figure out where...   I've added my code that defines editionRef and Edition.  Previously editionRef did not have a type, I've added one as above and updated the error message.

Comment: So this "_Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Edition'._" indicates that `this.editionService.getEdition(ed.id).valueChanges()` should never be allowed to return 'undefined' and the type of Observable should only be Edition.

Comment: OK so I was able to clear the errors, but not totally sure I'm doing this the right way.  

When I changed to `editionRef: Observable<Edition>`, it got mad bc the AngularFirestoreDocument from getEdition returns <Edition | undefined>.

Instead, I went the other way: `subscribe(([edition, sections, articles]: [Edition | undefined, Section[], Article[]]) => {` and did `if (!!edition)` in the 'do stuff' block.

Looks like I could also do `editonRef: Observable<Edition> = (... as Observable<Edition>)` instead.  

Would either of these be deemed more/less correct?

Comment: The first option would be considered "more correct" because you are actually indicating the typing required, where using `as` is typecasting something you're unsure of into something you need. The second will likely work, but doesn't "enforce" typing the way the first option does.

Comment: Got it, thanks very much.  Would you care to summarize as an answer for credit?  If not I will self-answer the question in case someone else has the same stumble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that somewhere along the chain of `editionRef -> edition -> Edition` you have an implicit `any` type. from the docs:

> Any variable, parameter or property that is initialized with null or
> undefined will have type any, even if strict null checks is turned on.

So I would start by trying to find an uninitialized, `undefined` or `null` variable within that chain.

The error

> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Edition'.

indicates that `this.editionService.getEdition(ed.id).valueChanges()` should never be allowed to return `undefined` and the type of Observable should only be `Edition`.

Finally, in your fix it is best to actually indicate the typing required to be enforced.

You *could* us `as` to typecast the type, but you're changing something you are unsure of into something you need. This option will likely work, but doesn't "enforce" typing the way the typing does.

So the best solution, as you placed in your comment is:

```
subscribe(([edition, sections, articles]: [Edition | undefined, Section[], Article[]]) => { ... }
```